# COBOL Replace char in string to digits

Tags: string, replace, cobol

In COBOL I need to replace each char within random alphanumeric string of 149 char with numbers.
1 needs to be replaced with 4,
2 with 7 etc...
The complexity comes with few char needs to be replaced by digit in tens:
'A' needs to be replaced with 19,
'B' needs to be replaced with 21 etc...

Could someone please help? The following code not quite works. I am not sure how to resolve problem with positions.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
  
   PROGRAM-ID.     PROG211.


  **************************************************
  *  DEFINE FILES TO BE BE USED
  **************************************************
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   
   INPUT-OUTPUT                 SECTION.
   
   FILE-CONTROL.
   
       SELECT IN-FILE      ASSIGN TO INFILE
              FILE STATUS IS WS-IN-STATUS.
              
       SELECT TOTALS-FILE   ASSIGN TO OUTTOT
              FILE STATUS IS WS-TOTALS-STATUS.
              
   DATA DIVISION.
   
  **************************************************
  *  DEFINE FILE LAYOUTS
  **************************************************
   FILE                         SECTION.
  
   FD  IN-FILE RECORDING MODE IS F.
   
   01  IN-REC.
       03 IN-BODY          PIC X(149).
       03 IN-CRLF          PIC XX.
       
   FD  TOTALS-FILE RECORDING MODE IS F.
   
  *** TOTALS-REC TWICE THE SIZE IN CASE CONVERTING ALL TO TENS DIGITS *** 
   01  TOTALS-REC.
       03 TOTALS-BODY      PIC X(298).
       03 TOTALS-CRLF      PIC XX.
   
   WORKING-STORAGE              SECTION.
   
   01  WS-IN-STATUS           PIC XX.
       88 IN-OK               VALUE '00'.
       88 IN-EOF              VALUE '10'.
       88 IN-VALID            VALUE '00', '10'.
 
   01  WS-TOTALS-STATUS        PIC XX.
       88 TOTALS-OK            VALUE '00'.
   
   01  WS-POS-IN           PIC 999.
   01  WS-POS-TOT          PIC 999.
   
   01 WS-CHARACTERS.
      04 BF             PIC X(24) VALUE '0123456789EFGHIKMNPQTUVZ'.
      04 AF             PIC X(24) VALUE '534916820717906256478310'.
      
   
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   MAIN-PROCESS                 SECTION.
   
       PERFORM A-100-INIT           
       PERFORM B-100-PROCESS UNTIL IN-EOF                   
       PERFORM C-100-TERM           
       DISPLAY 'PROGRAM FINISHED'           
       STOP RUN
       .
       
  ***************************************************
  *  INITIAL PROCESSING - OPEN FILES
  ***************************************************
   A-100-INIT               SECTION.
   
       OPEN INPUT  IN-FILE
        OUTPUT TOTALS-FILE
       
       IF IN-OK AND TOTALS-OK
          CONTINUE
       ELSE
          DISPLAY 'COULD NOT OPEN FILES'
          PERFORM Z-100-UNEXPECTED-ERROR
       END-IF
       
       PERFORM Y-100-READ-IN
       
   IF IN-EOF
      DISPLAY 'IN FILE IS EMPTY'
   END-IF
   .
       
   A-100-INIT-RETURN.
       EXIT.


  ***************************************************
  *  PROCESS EACH RECORD
  ***************************************************
   B-100-PROCESS            SECTION.
       
       INSPECT IN-REC
           CONVERTING BF
           TO         AF
   
   MOVE IN-REC           TO TOTALS-BODY
   
   MOVE 0  TO WS-POS-IN
   MOVE 0  TO WS-POS-TOT
   
   PERFORM VARYING WS-POS-IN FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL WS-POS-IN > 149
              
        EVALUATE IN-BODY (WS-POS-IN: )
         WHEN 'A'
              MOVE 21           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'B'
              MOVE 17           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'C'
              MOVE 13           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'D'
              MOVE 15           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'J'
              MOVE 11           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'L'
              MOVE 31           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'O'
              MOVE 23           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'R'
              MOVE 19           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'S'
              MOVE 10           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'W'
              MOVE 16           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'X'
              MOVE 18           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
         WHEN 'Y'
              MOVE 20           TO TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT: )
            
        END-EVALUATE

       END-PERFORM
   
   MOVE X'0D0A' TO TOTALS-CRLF         
   
   PERFORM Y-200-WRITE-TOTALS
   
       PERFORM Y-100-READ-MOO
          
          .
       
   B-100-PROCESS-RETURN.
       EXIT.



  ***************************************************
  *  TERMINATION PROCESSING - CLOSE FILES
  ***************************************************
   C-100-TERM               SECTION.
       
       CLOSE  IN-FILE
          TOTALS-FILE
       
       IF IN-OK AND TOTALS-OK
          CONTINUE
       ELSE
          DISPLAY 'COULD NOT CLOSE FILES'
          PERFORM Z-100-UNEXPECTED-ERROR
       END-IF      
       .

   C-100-TERM-RETURN.
       EXIT.

  ***************************************************
  *  READ RECORD
  ***************************************************
   Y-100-READ-IN               SECTION.
             
       READ IN-FILE
       
       IF NOT IN-VALID
      DISPLAY 'COULD NOT READ IN RECORD'
      PERFORM Z-100-UNEXPECTED-ERROR
   END-IF
   .
   
   Y-100-READ-IN-RETURN.
       EXIT.
       
  ***************************************************
  *  WRITE IN RECORD
  ***************************************************
   Y-200-WRITE-TOTALS               SECTION.
       
   WRITE TOTALS-REC
   
   IF NOT TOTALS-OK
      DISPLAY 'COULD NOT WRITE TOTALS RECORD'
      PERFORM Z-100-UNEXPECTED-ERROR
   END-IF
   .       
   Y-200-WRITE-TOTALS-RETURN.
       EXIT.
        
  ***************************************************
  *  UNEXPECTED ERROR SECTION
  ***************************************************
   Z-100-UNEXPECTED-ERROR               SECTION.
       
  
       DISPLAY 'IN STATUS IS ' WS-IN-STATUS
       DISPLAY 'TOTALS STATUS IS ' WS-TOTALS-STATUS
       
       STOP RUN
       .

   Z-100-TERM-RETURN.
       EXIT.
```

Comment: Of course. As this is no coding side please show your code and where you are stuck (you'll likely use either `PERFORM` to iterate over the source data or use COBOL-202x `FUNCTION SUBSTITUTE` (which is so far only available in GnuCOBOL and OpenCOBOL)

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match your code.  My understanding is that you want to replace SWXY with 19161820 display digits.  Is this correct?  What happens when you replace a 1 with a 4?  Is the replacement 4 or 04?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I  have now posted full code. Single digits and letters are easy and I am replacing them with INSPECT IN-REC CONVERTING BF TO AF. I have a problem with replacing the ones which needs to be replaced by two char numbers. I need to somehow input them in without overwriting others. The string will just get longer.

Comment: Gilbert Le Blanc, yes you are right, SWXY would become 10161820 and if its only double digits in the row the row will have 153 char.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use a common technique to place the one and two character translations into the output. To that end, I created a table defining all the translations in one place, used `SEARCH` to locate the specific translation, and `INSTRING` to place the translation into the output.

To test the code, I reduced the size of the fields to 9 and 18 positions.

I used lower-case for all significant changes included in this minimal working example ([MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

---

```
   WORKING-STORAGE              SECTION.
   01  IN-REC.
       03 IN-BODY              PIC X(9).
       88 test-1 value "012345678".
       88 test-2 value "9ABCDEFGH".
       88 test-3 value "IJKLMNOPQ".
       88 test-4 value "RSTUVWXYZ".
   
  *** TOTALS-REC TWICE THE SIZE IN CASE CONVERTING ALL TO TENS DIGITS *** 
   01  TOTALS-REC.
       03 TOTALS-BODY          PIC X(18).
   
   01  WS-POS-IN           PIC 999.
   01  WS-POS-TOT          PIC 999.
   
   01 WS-CHARACTERS.
    03 translations-defined.
     05 pic x value "0".  05 pic xx value "5 ".
     05 pic x value "1".  05 pic xx value "3 ".
     05 pic x value "2".  05 pic xx value "4 ".
     05 pic x value "3".  05 pic xx value "9 ".
     05 pic x value "4".  05 pic xx value "1 ".
     05 pic x value "5".  05 pic xx value "6 ".
     05 pic x value "6".  05 pic xx value "8 ".
     05 pic x value "7".  05 pic xx value "2 ".
     05 pic x value "8".  05 pic xx value "0 ".
     05 pic x value "9".  05 pic xx value "7 ".
     05 pic x value "A".  05 pic xx value "21".
     05 pic x value "B".  05 pic xx value "17".
     05 pic x value "C".  05 pic xx value "13".
     05 pic x value "D".  05 pic xx value "15".
     05 pic x value "E".  05 pic xx value "1 ".
     05 pic x value "F".  05 pic xx value "7 ".
     05 pic x value "G".  05 pic xx value "9 ".
     05 pic x value "H".  05 pic xx value "0 ".
     05 pic x value "I".  05 pic xx value "6 ".
     05 pic x value "J".  05 pic xx value "11".
     05 pic x value "K".  05 pic xx value "2 ".
     05 pic x value "L".  05 pic xx value "31".
     05 pic x value "M".  05 pic xx value "5 ".
     05 pic x value "N".  05 pic xx value "6 ".
     05 pic x value "O".  05 pic xx value "23".
     05 pic x value "P".  05 pic xx value "4 ".
     05 pic x value "Q".  05 pic xx value "7 ".
     05 pic x value "R".  05 pic xx value "19".
     05 pic x value "S".  05 pic xx value "10".
     05 pic x value "T".  05 pic xx value "8 ".
     05 pic x value "U".  05 pic xx value "3 ".
     05 pic x value "V".  05 pic xx value "1 ".
     05 pic x value "W".  05 pic xx value "16".
     05 pic x value "X".  05 pic xx value "18".
     05 pic x value "Y".  05 pic xx value "20".
     05 pic x value "Z".  05 pic xx value "0 ".
    03 redefines translations-defined.
     05 translate-entry occurs 36 indexed by search-pos.
      07 search-char pic x.
      07 translate-char pic xx.

   01 character-count comp pic 9(4).

   procedure division.
   begin.
       set test-1 to true
       perform translate-test
       set test-2 to true
       perform translate-test
       set test-3 to true
       perform translate-test
       set test-4 to true
       perform translate-test
       stop run
       .

   translate-test.
       display IN-BODY
       perform B-100-PROCESS
       display TOTALS-BODY
       display space
       .

  ***************************************************
  *  PROCESS EACH RECORD
  ***************************************************
   B-100-PROCESS            SECTION.
       
       move 1 to WS-POS-TOT
       move space to TOTALS-BODY
       PERFORM VARYING WS-POS-IN FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL WS-POS-IN > 9
           set search-pos to 1
           search translate-entry varying search-pos
           when IN-BODY (WS-POS-IN:1) = search-char (search-pos)
               unstring translate-char (search-pos)
                   delimited space
               into TOTALS-BODY (WS-POS-TOT:2)
               count in character-count
           add character-count to WS-POS-TOT
       END-PERFORM
       .
```

---

Output:

```
012345678
534916820

9ABCDEFGH
7211713151790

IJKLMNOPQ
611231562347

RSTUVWXYZ
19108311618200
```